# Unable to start hibernate session factory bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2, hibernate-annotations

Here is my hibernate config

```
 <bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:/localhost/testDB"/>
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="sample.model"/>
        <property name="annotatedPackages">
            <list>
                <value>sample.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I included this dependency

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected method not found: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(java.lang.Class)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getMethod(ClassUtils.java:627)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.<clinit>(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:79)
    ... 39 more
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It seems your configuration is not supported for hibernate version 3.5.6

Comment: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass is present only in Hibernate 4 and not in version 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use hibernate 3 and Adding this

```
<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext</prop>
```

So the final config is

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="sample.model"/>
        <property name="annotatedPackages">
            <list>
                <value>sample.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                   <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext</prop>
               </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your hibernate annotations jar file is the incorrect version.

You should already have `hibernate-core` as a dependency. If so you can comment out your `hibernate-annotations` dependency in your POM file.